# Magento 2 - add a custom input field below the cash on delivery radio button and save to quote_payment table

Tags: magento2, custom-field, cash-on-delivery, database-schema

Need to add an input field below the Cash on delivery radio button.

Implemented the code by this [link](http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/save-payment-method-with-additional-data-show-custom-field-on-payment-check) where the input is added below COD radio but the value is not added to the database.

Can anyone check what the wrong is on that code else provide the best solution to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: can you post your observer code?

Comment: You can find the observer code from the below link

https://github.com/Ejilarasan/Magento2.2.5.git

Comment: that code seems to save the payment data in relation to the payment method selected.

Comment: Is that possible for you to modify as per my requirement?. The input should be below "COD" radio button and once the place order is clicked that input data should save on quote_payment table.

Comment: I will try and post the solution here. assuming you have your own custom module already

Comment: Uploaded my whole module under this link.

https://github.com/Ejilarasan/Magento2.2.5.git

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89003/discussion-between-ejilarasan-j-and-magefms).

Answer (score 0):

> Just add **`banktransfer.html`**   inside **`Ibnab/CustomAttribute/view/frontend/web/template`**

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()" />
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <p data-bind="html: getInstructions()"></p>
        <fieldset data-bind="attr: {class: 'fieldset payment items allbank ' + getCode(), id: 'payment_form_' + getCode()}">
            <div class="field _required">
                <label data-bind="attr: {for: getCode() + '_bankowner'}" class="label">
                    <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Account Owner'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input data-validate="{'required-entry':true}" type="text" name="payment[bankowner]" class="input-text" value=""
                           data-bind="attr: {
                                    id: getCode() + '_bankowner',
                                    title: $t('Account Owner'),
                                    'data-container': getCode() + '-bankowner',
                                    'data-validate': JSON.stringify({'required':true})},
                                    valueUpdate: 'keyup' "/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {'title': $t('Place Order')},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked()),
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()}
                        "
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Change template in **`banktransfer-method.js`**
>   from:

```
 template: 'Ibnab_Additional/payment/banktransfer'
```

> to :

```
 template: 'Ibnab_CustomAttribute/banktransfer'
```

> Then `run setup:upgrade`
>   `run static-content:deploy`

And check if it works!

Comment: Really thanks for your effort but the above changes also not working as expected.

It's not added on the Admin's sales detail and the table "quote_payment" too.

Can you please review it from your end?

Comment: have you downloaded the updated module here https://github.com/fmsthird/magentocustomPaymentField ?

Comment: It works on mine.

Comment: Let me download the whole module from the git and try again now.

Comment: alright. Great . hopefully it will work for you

Comment: It's not working for me. Cleared cache and page cache folder under var. Done the below commands on terminal.

sudo chmod 777 -R var/* pub/* generated/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
sudo chmod 777 -R var/* pub/* generated/*

It's the same as I told before.

Comment: Not working even after replacing the updated module. Anything needs to done additionally?.

Comment: Could you please help to sort out this?

Comment: It works on me, just follow this: download the module from github link above. Remove the module in setup_module table in the database, then run setup:upgrade, then run setup:static-content:deploy -f